# Buscar elemento de lista en dataframe

Tags: python, string, lista, jupyter, replace

Tengo un dataframe con una columna `DESCRIPCION` y necesito buscar si alguno de los elementos de la lista `MARCAS` está en él. En caso de que exista, que ese valor se borre de allí y se pegue en otra columna.

Acá paso un ejemplo:

```
descripcion = 'acople rapido ½ con stop bremen'
marcas = ['bremen', 'wembley', 'casa']
print(marcas in descripcion)
```

El primer error que me arroja es este:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

O sea que no me permite buscar con `IN` elementos de una lista.
También intenté usar luego el método `REPLACE` pero no me funciona a menos que la coincidencia entre el elemento de la lista `MARCAS` y `DESCRIPCION` sea exacto.

Comment: tu ejemplo no concuerda con tu titulo, pero segun lo que intentas en codigo yo haría algo como `[print(val) for val  in marcas if val in descripcion]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar un elemento dentro de un `dataframe` usando un `list`puedes hacer uso de `str.contains`

El código sería algo así (reconstrui tu dataframe para poder simular el ejercicio):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'descripcion':['acople rapido ½ con stop bremen']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

marcas = ['bremen', 'wembley', 'casa']
```

Así se usaría `str.contains`: Uniríamos tu `df['descripcion']` a un regex con el operador `or` representado con `|` para filtrar el dataframe

```
df["encontrado"] = df[df['descripcion'].str.contains("|".join(marcas))]
```

El resultado sería:

```
                       descripcion                            encontrado
0  acople rapido ½ con stop bremen  acople rapido ½ con stop bremen
```

La parte donde indicas

> En caso de que exista, que ese valor se borre de allí y se pegue en
> otra columna.

honestamente no lo comprendí. Es recomendable que pongas en tu pregunta un ejercicio con el resultado esperado para ser más eficiente en mi respuesta. Espero esto te pueda ayudar.

Código final:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'descripcion':['acople rapido ½ con stop bremen']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
marcas = ['bremen', 'wembley', 'casa']

df["encontrado"] = df[df['descripcion'].str.contains("|".join(marcas))]
print(df)
```

Comment: Olvidé comentar que si quieres que la búsqueda ignore mayúsculas/minúsculas solo debes modificar la línea de filtrado así `df["encontrado"] = df[df['descripcion'].str.contains("|".join(marcas), case=False)]`. Es decir, agregas `case=False`